# tablayout shadow/elevation for pre-lollipop

Tags: android, toolbar, android-4.4-kitkat, android-tablayout, android-elevation

I have a tablayout inside an AppBarLayout. I am trying to add a shadow view below the tabbarlayout for pre-lollipop versions. The shadow view shows up, however when I scroll down, the shadow view doesn't seem transparent. It look like as though there is a padding below tablayout, between the tabindicator and shadow. However if I use the same shadow view with just under a Toolbar, it seems to be transparent when I scroll up. Can someone tell me if there is anything different to add shadow for tablayouts?

main_layout-

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/include_coordinator_layout"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mtext_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/mtext_view"
        android:text="@string/retry_button"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And this is my include_coordinator_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout  
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/main_content"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
       android:id="@+id/appbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:background="@color/tab_layout_color"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/shadow_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_shadow"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is my toolbar_shadow drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:endColor="#88333333"
        android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have your layout in a `LinearLayout`?

Either

Change LinearLayout to RelativeLayout and add `android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"`, `android:paddingTop="-5dp"` and `android:clipToPadding="false"` to your ViewPager (or use ConstraintLayout and similar method), switch the order of the toolbar and view pager

or

Change it to a FrameLayout, reorder the views so that the ViewPager is first and then put `android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sizeOfToolBarAndTabsWithoutShadow"` where the dimen is the set size of the toolbar & tabs (without shadow). You might want to do this, because I seem to remember some visual artefacts with some scrolling views and clipToPadding

Why?

Because the size of the `AppBarLayout` view includes your shadow, so any basic view group (LinearLayout) won't know how to lay the next view (your viewpager) out so that the shadow slightly overlaps the content - which has to be drawn last, so that the top of the view pager doesn't cover the shadow

Comment: sorry included the entire code. Can you please tell me where exactly to change it to FrameLayout, since it is in a CoordinatorLayout?